# Check if resource already exists or not using serverless

Tags: serverless-framework, amazon-waf, serverless-plugins

I want to add if else condition in Serverless where I want to check if a particular resource (eg. AWS WAF)exists or not.

I am using [serverless-plugin-ifelse](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse#:%7E:text=You%20cannot%20have%20both%20attributes%20in%20serverless.&text=This%20plugin%20allows%20you%20to,attributes%20in%20the%20yml%20file)

I want to know if it is possible to do this and how should I approach this. Please feel free to give any examples related to if-else and WAF